# Regex - How to match all text between a given word

Tags: regex

This is my text

```
FUNCTION 1
    Some text
FUNCTION 2
    Some text
FUNCTION 3
    Some text
```

I want to get the following matches

Match 1

```
FUNCTION 1
    Some text
```

Match 2

```
FUNCTION 2
    Some text
```

Match 3

```
FUNCTION 3
    Some text
```

The pattern that I have come up with so far is

```
FUNCTION[\s\S]*FUNCTION
```

[Online demo link](http://regexr.com/3e9rk)

Comment: `FUNCTION[\s\S]*?(?=\nFUNCTION)`

Comment: Which programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) regex:

```
FUNCTION(?:(?!FUNCTION)[\s\S])*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kZ2qM7/1)

The `(?:(?!FUNCTION)[\s\S])*` is the token that matches any char (`[\s\S]`) that is not starting a `FUNCTION` character sequence. Basically, it is similar to [`FUNCTION\[\S\s\]*?(?=FUNCTION|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/sV7iL5/1) as far as the final results are concerned, just the lazy matching is turned to a construct that matches up to the next sequence *without requiring it to appear at the end*, hence we can omit the `|$` alternative.

If the word `FUNCTION` appears on a separate line surrounded with tabs/spaces, you may unroll it as

```
^[ \t]*FUNCTION[ \t]*(?:\r?\n(?![ \t]*FUNCTION[ \t]*$).*)*
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kZ2qM7/2) (note the use of the `m` multiline modifier here).

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was look for